# Understanding spin & spatial components of wave-functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space

I would like to understand the following statement:

> The $S$ and $P$ states can be expressed as products of the spin wavefunctions, $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$, and the spatial wavefunctions, $|nlm_l\rangle$, using Clebsh-Gordan coefficients:
>   $$|2S_{1/2}M_J=1/2\rangle=|200\rangle|+\rangle; $$
>   $$|2P_{1/2}M_J=1/2\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|211\rangle|-\rangle-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|210\rangle|+\rangle.$$

My question: how to obtain the expression for $|2P_{1/2}M_J=1/2\rangle$? I do not understand how Clebsh-Gordan coefficients appear in this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clebsh-Gordan coefficients are involved because you are looking at a state in the coupled basis of $L$ and $S$. Specifically, your atomic state denoted by the term symbol $^{2}{\rm P}_{\frac{1}{2}}$ has orbital angular momentum $L=1$, spin $S=\frac{1}{2}$ and total angular momentum of $J=\frac{1}{2}$. This state is a superposition of states in the uncoupled basis, as you write in your question.

To elaborate, this procedure is known as addition of angular momentum. You define $\boldsymbol{J}=\boldsymbol{L}+\boldsymbol{S}$ and want new states with definite $J^{2}$ and $m_{J}$ quantum numbers. Your new basis as expressible by the old one $\left|L,m_{L};S,m_{S}\right>$ using Clebsh-Gordan coefficients

$$\left|J,m_{J}\right>=\sum_{m_{L},m_{S}}C_{L,m_{L};S,m_{S};J,m_{J}}\left|L,m_{L};S,m_{S}\right>$$